# É possível exportar um jar e a documentação juntos?

Tags: intellij-idea

Eu estou usando a Intellj IDE e exportando um projeto para um arquivo `jar` usando os Artifacts . Porém, quando eu uso esse jar em outros projetos os comentários estilo javadoc dos métodos não aparecem.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso ?